# Как получить доступ к папкам другого (своего!) сайта

Tags: linux, файловая-система, доступ

Есть сайт, допустим, example.com

Админка вынесена в отдельный сайт admin.example.com
Есть полный доступ к обоим сайтам.

Как в админ. сайте организовать работу с папками основного сайта как со "своими"? Например, чтоб товару закачать фото в админке - и чтоб фото закачалось в папку основного сайта, и в базу записался путь основного сайта?

Можно не полный ответ - хотя бы поисковые слова подскажите :)

Comment: 1. В файловой системе есть симлинки - можно в командной строке настроить чтобы upload/ была симлинком на каталог основного сайта. Или наоборот. Возможно придется настроить веб-сервер, некоторые не ходят по симлинкам, нужно принудительно включать эту опцию. 2. `и в базу записался путь основного сайта` - тут зависит от скриптов, на котором это работает. Трудно сказать, что там записывается. Уточните в вопросе движок. И зачем собственно выносить админку на отдельный домен?

Comment: @Total Pusher  Спасибо, про симлинки уже читаю. Движок - Laravel+React

Полчему отдельный домен? На основном авторизации передрались: sanctum для Аякс-запросов и Sentinel для пользователей админки

Comment: Laravel для сохранения файлов использует фасад Storage. Можно в его конфиге прописать в root абсолютный путь к каталогу другого сайта. Думаю, также будет работать. `artisan storage:link` кстати тоже симлинки использует. Если интересно, симлинки можно делать на симлинки

Comment: @Total Pusher  Спасибо!